# Run a bash array with pipes

Tags: arrays, bash, pipeline

How can I run a command line from a `bash` array containing a pipeline?

For example, I want run `ls | grep x` by means of:

```
$ declare -a pipeline
$ pipeline=(ls)
$ pipeline+=("|")
$ pipeline+=(grep x)
$ "${pipeline[@]}"
```

But I get this:

```
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access grep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access x: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short form: You can't (without writing some code), and it's a feature, not a bug.

If you're doing things in a safe way, you're protecting your data from being parsed as code (syntax). What you explicitly want here, however, is to treat data as code, but only in a controlled way.

What you can do is iterate over elements, use `printf '%q ' "$element"` to get a safely quoted string if they aren't a pipeline, and leave them unsubstituted if they are.

After doing that, and ONLY after doing that, can you safely eval the output string.

```
eval_args() {
  local outstr=''
  while (( $# )); do
    if [[ $1 = '|' ]]; then
      outstr+="| "
    else
      printf -v outstr '%s%q ' "$outstr" "$1"
    fi
    shift
  done
  eval "$outstr"
}
eval_args "${pipeline[@]}"
```

By the way -- it's much safer NOT TO DO THIS. Think about the case where you're processing a list of files, and one of them is named `|`;  this strategy could be used by an attacker to inject code. Using separate lists for the before and after arrays, or making only one side of the pipeline an array and hardcoding the other, is far better practice.

Comment: +1, but the recommendation to not write code like this *cannot* be stressed enough.

Answer (score 1):

Close - just add `eval`:

```
$ eval ${pipeline[@]}
```

Comment: But that's very fragile and error-prone, since whitespace and quotes and asterisks and so on can be processed at multiple stages.

Comment: Isn't that what shell scripting is all about? ;-)

Comment: @CarlNorum No, shell scripting is _not_ about gratuitous security holes. Not if you're doing it right, anyhow.

Comment: So much for the winky face, I guess.  OP's question doesn't have any of these problems anyway.  You're welcome to write an answer, too.

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm working on one. Building and testing something robust takes time.

Comment: ...in terms of why the original is wrong: Try it with more interesting inputs. For instance: `pipeline=( "cat" "filename with spaces" "|" tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' )`; the form you gave will treat `filename`, `with` and `spaces` as three different arguments to `cat`.

Comment: The op has full control over and explicitly defined the inputs in this case, so no need to avoid the simple eval. +1 for this post

Comment: @ClaytonStanley If one is explicitly defining inputs, there would be no point to using arrays at all. Thus, the ONLY circumstance in which this question possibly makes sense (that is, the place in which it could be put to practical use) is one where the array is built by code, in which using `eval` is not so predictable as it is here.

Comment: One such use of an array is to deconstruct a thorny command into its components, each argument on a separate line (e.g. in a heredoc) for easy comprehension and editing.  Such a command would be explicitly defined in the source, but run as "${command[@]}".  The explicit command may even be augmented further programmatically to suit different purposes. I use this technique frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
bash -c  "${pipeline[*]}"
```

Comment: Try it with something more interesting. For instance: `pipeline=( "cat" "filename with spaces" "|" tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' )`; the form you gave will treat `filename`, `with` and `spaces` as three different arguments to `cat`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you make a valid point. Having said that, it appears that the OP is looking to run something from the command line and is in control of inputs. Not sure if files with spaces in their names are that common an occurrence on UNIX. On the whole, I think your `eval_args` function is probably the way to go and I am going to +1 it.

Comment: Even if a filename containing the literal string `$(rm -rf /)` is an _uncommon_ occurrence, you still don't want to eval it when one does happen. Data loss incidents and security breaches are hopefully uncommon occurrences, but you don't ignore the potential for their precursors to happen because of that.